# TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was making a command for my discord bot and i counter an error in the process I'm pretty new to programming so forgive me if there was something very simple that i couldn't figure out

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at Object.callback (C:\Users\Aoshey\Downloads\Nol\bot test\modules\setimage.mod.js:11:30)
    at ReputationCore.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aoshey\node_modules\reputation-core\builtin_modules\commands.mod.js:54:33)
    at ReputationCore.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at ReputationCore.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aoshey\node_modules\reputation-core\reputationCore.js:35:10)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\Aoshey\node_modules\reputation-core\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Aoshey\node_modules\reputation-core\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:108:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Aoshey\node_modules\reputatiocore\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:336:35)
```

code:

```
const fsn = require("fs-nextra");
const colors = require("colors");

exports.id = "setimg";

exports.onLoad = api => {
    api.commands.add("setimg", (msg) => {
        let employeeRole = msg.guild.roles.get("745410836901789749");

        if (msg.member.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === '745410836901789749')) {
            if(msg.channel.id == 746423099871985755) {
                fsn.readJSON("./orders.json").then((orderDB) => {
                    let ticketID = msg.content.substring(9);
                    let order = orderDB[ticketID];

                    // If the order doesn't exist.
                    if(order === undefined) {
                        msg.reply("Couldn't find that order. Try again!");

                        return;
                    }
                    //and the rest of the command's code
```

Answer (score 0):

So you defined `employeeRole`, but aren't using it. Instead of asking if the user has the role `employeeRole`, you do something that is not possible in your first if-statement.

```js
if(msg.member.roles.cache.has(employeeRole)) {...}
```

Change your first if-statement into the code I gave you here and it should be fixed. Now you are asking if the user has the `employeeRole`.

P.S.: You need to add `.cache` at your `employeeRole` so it has to be

```js
let employeeRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.get("745410836901789749");
```

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined```

Comment: Okay then try `let employeeRole = msg.guild.roles.fetch("745410836901789749");` or `let employeeRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "745410836901789749");`

Comment: after i added `let employeeRole = msg.guild.roles.fetch("745410836901789749");` i got an error saying "TypeError: msg.guild.roles.fetch" is not a function` then i removed it and added `let employeeRole = msg.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "745410836901789749");` it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"

Comment: Does it work with the version that you had? `let employeeRole = msg.guild.roles.get("745410836901789749");` was your version. Because for me this does not work.

Comment: i think the issue is with the `if(msg.member.roles.cache.has(employeeRole)) {...}` days ago i had `let employeeRole = msg.guild.roles.get("745410836901789749");

  if(msg.member.roles.has(employeeRole.id)) {rest of the code}` and it working fine in a server where it had the role it requested but if the command was used in another server it crashes the bot throwing an error i also had an `} else {` at the end of the code and it also crashes the bot